# Whats the difference between time changing electromagnetic field and electromagnetic waves?

Tags: communication, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

When a charge is accelerated its said that it produces electromagnetic waves. They also say that an accelerating charges produces time changing electromagnetic field and which when passes through a conductor induces voltage in it. I wonder are these two terms same ? Electromagnetic waves is the concept used in communication while electromagnetic field/induction is the concept mostly used in motors,transformers and generators. Please explain. I am confused on it.

Comment: Recently i found this also. "Thus, EMR is sometimes referred to as the far field. In this language, the near field refers to EM fields near the charges and current that directly produced them, specifically, electromagnetic induction and electrostatic induction phenomena." Will anyone explain that more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic distinction here is between "field" and "wave". An EM wave is a radiation of power. That radiation contains an electric and a magnetic field content. Both fields are in phase and, together they have a ratio of 377 in a vacuum. Without the phase alignment or the correct amplitude ratio they don't travel very far but can (if the circumstances are favourable) form a coherent EM wave such as at about one wavelength distant from a correctly made radio antenna.

Why 377 ohms?

Thats the impedance of free-space governed by the square root of the ratio of magnetic permeability to electric permeability: -

[image]

The term "electromagnetic field" is looser and could be used to mean or imply: -

- EM wave (due to it time changing as per the question title)
- Near fields around an antenna
- The magnetic field caused by an electric field

Comment: When an ac voltage/current is applied to a conductor it will give both time changing electromagnetic field and electromagnetic waves and Electromagnetic waves will travel a longer distance than the electromagnetic field ?  @andy aka

Comment: Once an em wave is formed the fields individually reduce with distance. When not formed into an em wave the reduction rapidly becomes an inverse cube law. For this absolutely important reason, this is why radio is so important!

Comment: "Once an em wave is formed the fields individually reduce with distance. When not formed into an em wave the reduction rapidly becomes an inverse cube law." Is it not true that both EM field and EMwaves are formed every time the charge is accelerated ?

Comment: My definition for an em wave as given in my answer means that unless the antenna impedance matching criteria is largely met then an em field might be somewhere between virtually zero and useful. I know that is a generalization but you have no example stated so that's realistically my best response.

Comment: For instance, you can use a ferrite rod antenna to pick up long wave radio transmissions because it captures the mag field of an incident em wave. However, try and use that rod as an antenna to produce an em transmission and you might as well try pushing a puddle of water up a 1 mile high hill.

Comment: i found this also @andy aka. "Electromagnetic waves are definitely time varying electromagnetic fields.

If you ask this question to a mathematician, she will reply that they are both waves because they both are solutions to the wave equation.

Comment: To an engineer there may be a difference between solutions to the wave equation that propagate and those that do not. He may refer to the former as a wave and the latter as time varying field.

Comment: The field around an antenna is often divided between near field and far field. The far field propagates and is likely to be called a wave. In the near field, there are both non-propagating components and propagating components. Close to the antenna, the non-propagating component is so much stronger than the propagating component, that the near field may be referred to as a non-propagating time varying field."

Comment: Yes, it is not clearly defined in my opinion and I personally like to call a wave something that carries power. For instance, when you apply a voltage to one end of a piece of coax, current and voltage flow together in the ratio of the characterisitic impedance and this, to my mind is a wave comprising two fields.

Comment: hmmm. So both are same with a distinction that one propagates while other does not. So do you think that the one that propagates is then used for the communication through modulation, like microwaves and radio waves while those which can not propagates are just helpful in nearby induction ?

Comment: My simple answer is that the near field doesn't contain what i call EM waves hence you either draw energy down from the mag, or the electric field.